# Prove that a language is bounded if and only if it's finite

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata

Let's assume $L$ is a language. $L$ is *bounded* if for some natural number $n \in \mathbb N$ applies $|x| ≤ n$, where $|x|$ is a length of a string, with every $x \in L$. Let's also assume that $L$ lies in a finite set of alphabets $\Sigma$.

How to prove that $L$ is bounded if and only if it's finite?

Comment: Isn't it trivial? Or are you looking for a very strict mathematical proof like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548806/a-finite-set-always-has-a-maximum-and-a-minimum)?

Comment: I'm looking for a strict mathematical proof for this problem.

Comment: This is only true for languages over finite alphabets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim holds only for languages over finite alphabets.

#### Bounded $L$ $\implies$ Finite $L$

Let $\Sigma$ be the alphabet of $L$ and $L$ be bounded by some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The largest possible such $L$, call it $L^\#$, is $\bigcup_{\,i=0}^{\,n} \Sigma^i$ elements. $L^\#$ is finite since $|L^\#| = \sum_{i=0}^{n} |\Sigma|^i$. Therefore, any $L \subseteq L^\#$ must also be finite.

#### Finite $L$ $\implies$ Bounded $L$

Let $x^\#$ denote the longest string in $L$. Such a string must always exist since $L$ is finite.

Then, $\forall x \in L \ldotp |x| \leq |x^\#|$ and thus, $L$ is bounded.

---

A simple counterexample to the infinite alphabet case:

Consider an infinite alphabet $\Sigma = \{ s_0, s_1, ... \}$. The language $L = \Sigma$ is bounded since $\forall x \in L \ldotp |x| \leq 1$, but is infinite.